# Notice: Undefined variable: eT1 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How to access the ChoiceType (Radiobutton) submitted value in Symfony2 while working with Doctrine2
I am trying to update the value of eT1 and eT2 property of the events entity. The input value from two different ChoiceType(Radiobutton) is stored in the eT1 and eT2 variables after the user submits. when i try to use the $events->setET1($eT1) method, it gives an error - Notice: Undefined variable: eT1
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
Here is my Controller code

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\events;
//use AppBundle\Entity\eventtype;
use AppBundle\Entity\users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $events = new events();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($events)
                ->add('eT1', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Poker' => 1,
                        'Chess' => 2,
                        'Cricket' => 3,
                        'Marbles' => 4,
                        'Football' => 5,
                    ),
                    'choices_as_values' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Choose After Breakfast Event',
                ))
                ->add('eT2', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'choices' => array(
                        'Poker' => 1,
                        'Chess' => 2,
                        'Cricket' => 3,
                        'Marbles' => 4,
                        'Football' => 5,
                    ),
                    'choices_as_values' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'label' => 'Choose After Snacks Event',
                ))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
                ->getForm();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->submit($request);

            $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
            $events->setUser($user);

            $x = $events->getUser()->getID();

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:events')->findOneBy(array('user' => $x));
//                var_dump($events);
//                exit;
                if (!$events) {
                    echo 'insert';
                    // tells Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
                    $em->persist($events);

                    // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                } else {
                    echo 'update';
//                    var_dump($form);
//                    exit;
                    $events->setET1($eT1);
                    $events->setET2($eT2);
//                  $em->persist($events);
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

}
```

Below is the users entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\usersRepository")
 */
class users extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="events", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $event;


//    public function __construct()
//    {
//        parent::__construct(); 
//         }

    }
```

Below is the events entity where the setET1($eT1) is defined

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * events
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="events")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\eventsRepository")
 */
class events {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ET1", type="integer")
     */
    protected $eT1;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ET2", type="integer")
     */
    protected $eT2;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="users", inversedBy="event")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
        protected $user;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param users $user
     * @return events
     */
    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return events
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }


    /**
     * Set eT1
     *
     * @param integer $eT1
     * @return events
     */
    public function setET1($eT1) {
        $this->eT1 = $eT1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eT1
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getET1() {
        return $this->eT1;
    }

    /**
     * Set eT2
     *
     * @param integer $eT2
     * @return events
     */
    public function setET2($eT2) {
        $this->eT2 = $eT2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eT2
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getET2() {
        return $this->eT2;
    }

//    public function __construct()
//    {
//        parent::__construct();
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Your form will return the populated entity, so you can do this:

```
$eventFromForm = $form->getData(); // This is an instance of events()

$events->setET1($eventFromForm->getET1());
$events->setET2($eventFromForm->getET2());

$em->persist($events);
$em->flush();
```

---

$eT1 isn't defined (obviously) I'm guessing that you're trying to fetch the eT1 value from the form, in which case you'll need to do this:

```
$formData = $form->getData();
$events->setET1($formData['eT1']);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for

Comment: after adding 
`$formData = $form->getData();
                    $events->setET1($formData['eT1']);
                    $events->setET2($formData['eT2']);
`

now it gives me the error - Error: Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\events as array 500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException